# Danger in corrupting file during unexpected shutdown

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I am logging data via:

```
with open('filename.txt','a') as fid:
    fid.write(line_of_data)
```

Granted, the amount of time the file is open is short for each write, but I will write data every second making it extremely repetitive.  Since this is being used on a remote system there is always the chance that power will be interrupted causing the computer to shutdown.  If power is cut in the middle of a fid.write() will the whole file become corrupt, or, since it was opened to "append" will only the last line be lost?

Comment: In CPython, file objects are implemented using the C `FILE` type. So I suspect that the answer to this question is the same as the answer to "in C, what happens if power is cut when I'm writing to my `FILE` object?" Maybe that question already exists on SO :-)

Comment: Exactly what happens depends on things like [Page caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), and whether you're using a [Journaling file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system). FWIW, NTFS on Windows and ext3 & ext4 on Linux are Journaling file systems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It actually depends on the filesystem and operating system. When you "write" to a file it may not really means write to actual harddrive - it may be buffered by an OS, for example, and never actually "make it" to the hard drive itself. 
You should not assume anything in that case other than everything may happen.
If you need some form of persistent writing - you probably need to use specialized libraries which may add required layers of security

Comment: May be correct but not helpful.  Please be more specific.